# Need to understand a simple example of overwritting the input by the output

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameters

My question may be stupid but I need to understand a simple example about the overwritting of input values by previous output values in a function.

Here's this simple snippet code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void computeSquare(int input[], int output[]) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        output[i] = input[i] * input[i];
}

int main(void) {

    int i, j;

    int input[5];
    int output[5];
    int *ptr;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        input[i] = i;

    // Pointer to do the link between 2 calls of computeSquare
    ptr = input;

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        computeSquare(ptr, output);
        ptr = output;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        printf("output[%d] = %d\n", j, output[j]);

}
```

As you can see, I have 2 arrays (`input` and `output`) and I compute the square of each value of `input` array, then I store the results in `output` array. I repeat the process by assigning `output` with `input` for each call of `computeSquare` function : I do this using `ptr` pointer.

I don't understand why I don't get valid results at the execution (when I am printing `output` values).

I thought that I could use the same address (actually the the address of the first element for first and second argument of function) when I do :

```
computeSquare(ptr, output);
  ptr = output;
```

I thought that, in `computeSquare` function, I could have :

```
 output[i]= output[i]*output[i];
```

such that `output[i]` value would be replace by `output[i]*output[i]`.

I don't know where my reasoning is not good,

Thanks

Comment: suggestions: 1) #define that `5` with a meaningful name and use that meaningful name throughout the code  2) in C, an array name degrades to pointer to that array, so the variable `ptr` is not needed and only clutters the code

Comment: suggest 1) eliminate the `input[]` array, initialize the output[] array instead  2) eliminate the `ptr` variable  3) (due to int overflow) use `uint64_t` rather than `int` for the output[] array type  4) modify the format string of `printf()` to use "%ld" rather than "%d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasoning is correct, and so is the answer. Its just that the values are overflowing the int. Convert the array to float and it will work just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void computeSquare(float input[], float output[]) {

  int i;

  for (i=0; i< 5; i++)
     output[i]= input[i]*input[i];
  }

int main(void) {

  int i,j;

  float input[5];
  float output[5];
  float *ptr;

  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
     input[i] = i;

  // Pointer to do the link between 2 calls of computeSquare
  ptr = input;

  for (j=0; j<5; j++)
     {
      computeSquare(ptr, output);
      ptr = output;
for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
     printf("output[%d] = %f\n", k, output[k]);
     }
for (j=0; j<5; j++)
     printf("output[%d] = %f\n", j, output[j]);


  return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is too complicated, this simplified approach prints the squares array

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRLEN 5

void computeSquare(int input[], int output[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        output[i] = input[i] * input[i];
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int input[ARRLEN];
    int output[ARRLEN];
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        input[i] = i;
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        computeSquare(input, output);
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        printf("output[%d] = %d\n", i, output[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
output[0] = 0
output[1] = 1
output[2] = 4
output[3] = 9
output[4] = 16
```

But, looking closer, you said you want to overwrite the input values with their squares. When I tried to modify this so it overwrites the original input values it misfires, because you call the function for each array element which in turn also computes avery array element. The result was

```
input[0] = 0
input[1] = 1
input[2] = 0
input[3] = -501334399
input[4] = 0
```

So my first code worked, but to overwrite the values passed, you have to get rid of one of the double loops, and I choose to do this in `main` and not in the function, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRLEN 5

void computeSquare(int input[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        input[i] = input[i] * input[i];
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int input[ARRLEN];
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        input[i] = i;
    computeSquare(input);         // <-- don't iterate, because the function does
    for (i=0; i<ARRLEN; i++)
        printf("input[%d] = %d\n", i, input[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
output[0] = 0
output[1] = 1
output[2] = 4
output[3] = 9
output[4] = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overflowing an int here (since you repeat your square five times):

```
for (j=0; j<5; j++)
{
    computeSquare(ptr, output);
    ptr = output;
}
```

For 0 and 1 no matter how many times you multiply it will not change values. However even for 2 the results you'll get after each iteration are:

```
it 0: 2^1 * 2^1   = 2^2
it 1: 2^2 * 2^2   = 2^4
it 2: 2^4 * 2^4   = 2^8
it 3: 2^8 * 2^8   = 2^16
it 4: 2^16 * 2^16 = 2^32
```

While typical maximum value of an int is `2^31 - 1`

Try decreasing number of iterations you need to perform or use a long type (which still will overflow for bigger numbers).